# Usage of the verb "pore"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I'm familiar with the expression "pore over", meaning to examine carefully. However, I just looked at the [definition of "pore" in Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pore), and it has confused me some!

> 1. to gaze intently
> 2. to read or study attentively —usually used with over
> 3. to reflect or meditate steadily

1. "to gaze intently". How would this be used? Could you "pore at" a person? Or "pore into" their eyes?
2. "to read or study attentively - usually used with over". As far as I'm aware, the final phrase could be changed to "always used with over or through." Is this correct, or are there other prepositions that can be used?
3. "to reflect or meditate steadily". How would this one be used? It's perfectly fine to just say "I meditated"; can you say "I pored" to mean the same thing? You can also meditate or reflect "on" something. Can you similarly pore "on" something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED provides similar explanations to Merriam Webster, indicating that although *over* is the usual following preposition, others are possible. It shows examples from the time of Chaucer, and the older ones clearly indicate a variety of structures (*on*, *upon*, *in*, *through* as well as *over*).

As regards the 20th century, some, from 1922, and 1949 indicate a surviving use of *pore* with *on* and *through* as qualifying prepositions. Otherwise *over* seems to have become the only follower preposition in use with *pore*.

**Note that the below extract only concerns sense 1b of *pore*. However at the end I have given two other senses (2 & 3), both stated to be obsolete (1788 latest), where *pore* seems to have been used without preposition. My supposition is that these uses have been superseded by *peer*. And we do *peer into*, *peer through* and *peer at***.

**The OED gives the etymology of *pore* as "unknown", though it accepts it is probably related to *peer* (also spelled *pire* and *pyre*).**

> 1b. To examine a book, map, etc., with fixed attention; to study or
>   read earnestly or with intense concentration; to be absorbed in
>   reading or study. Freq. with prepositions, esp. over.
>
> ▸c1387–95   Chaucer Canterbury Tales Prol. 185   What sholde he studie
>   and make hym seluen wood, Vpon a book in cloystre alwey to poure
>   [c1415 Lansd. powre].
>
> ▸c1449   R. Pecock Repressor (1860) 87   Thouȝ ȝe wolden labore and
>   powre and dote alle the daies of ȝoure lijf in the Bible aloon.
>
> c1475  (▸c1399)    Mum & Sothsegger (Cambr. Ll.4.14) (1936) Prol. 71
>   (MED),   Þouȝ þat elde opyn it..And poure on it preuyly..It shulde not
>   apeire hem a peere.
>
> 1594   J. Lyly Mother Bombie i. iii. sig. B4v,   In stead of poaring
>   on a booke, you shall holde the plough.
>
> 1610   P. Holland tr. W. Camden Brit. To Rdr. sig. 4,   I haue poored
>   vpon many an old Rowle.
>
> 1675   W. Wycherley Country-wife i. 7   Mistresses are like Books; if
>   you pore on them too much, they doze you, and make you unfit for
>   Company.
>
> 1718   Free-thinker No. 37. 2   He rises by Three in the Morning to
>   pore over Mathematicks.
>
> 1771   J. Beattie Minstrel: Bk. 1st liii. 27   Where dark cold-hearted
>   sceptics, creeping, pore Through microscope of metaphysic lore.
>
> 1820   Keats Hyperion: a Fragm. ii, in Lamia & Other Poems 175   No,
>   no-where can unriddle, though I search, And pore on Nature's universal
>   scroll.
>
> 1876   L. Stephen Hours in Libr. 2nd Ser. vii. 322   He had pored over
>   their pages till he knew them by heart.
>
> 1879   L. Stephen Hours in Libr. 3rd Ser. iii. 98   That disposition
>   which..delights in poring over its own morbid emotions.
>
> 1908   L. M. Montgomery Anne of Green Gables xxx. 345   I've pored
>   over that geometry until I know every proposition in the first book
>   off by heart.
>
> 1922   Times 24 Mar. 10/3   The old Flemish Bible on the pictures of
>   which he pored in childhood.
>
> 1949   C. P. Snow Time of Hope i. iv. 38   She pored with anxious
>   concentration through the advertisement columns of the local papers.
>
> 1991   G. Ehrlich Islands, Universe, Home iii. 28   We pore over maps,
>   chart our expeditions.
>
> 2. trans. To bring or put (oneself) into some state by poring. Chiefly in to pore one's eyes out: to blind oneself, ruin one's eyesight, or
>      tire one's eyes by close reading or overstudy. Obs.
> 3. intr. To look with half-shut eyes; to look closely, as a short-sighted person; to peer. Obs.

Comment: I think I disagree that the 1922 and 1949 references provide evidence that *on* and *through* are still acceptable **now.** OED is a historical dictionary, and those entries only show that those prepositions were acceptable when they were used (and so, *over* has been OK since at least 1718 and was still in 1991, but there's no evidence **in that entry** that even that is still acceptable in 2016, although it's only a passage of 25 years and one might assume it's likely).

Comment: Well, I still say 'pore over', don't you? And I don't suggest the 'on and 'through' are still acceptable. I was just surprised they had been used as recently as that.

Comment: @Andrew: I was going to comment that *to pore **through*** still seems perfectly "current" to me. But [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pored+through&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpored%20through%3B%2Cc0) shows that in fact this particular preposition has become *far* more common over the past century than it ever was before. I think *to pore **on*** is well past its sell-by date, though.